# Get days property from numpy.ndarray of timedelta objects

Tags: datetime, casting, numpy, python-2.7, timedelta

I have a `numpy.ndarray`. The first two columns are dates of type `datetime.datetime`. I would like to find the difference in months (as a float) between the two where I define this as (difference in days)*(12/365). So I would like to get access to the .days property of the timedelta objects returned by subtracting two datetimes.

I can't do this: `(MyArray[1] - MyArray[0]).days` because Python doesn't know to expect timedelta objects. In C# I might try casting like this:

```
((timedelta)(MyArray[1] - MyArray[0])).days
```

What's the way to do this in Python (numpy)? Do I need to loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not doable without iterating on your array of `timedelta`

```
deltas = MyArray[1]-MyArray[0]
diff_days = np.fromiter((d.days for d in deltas), dtype=float, count=len(deltas))
```

Here, we're using `np.fromiter` with the `count` argument to be more efficient (it preallocates the size of the array).

Note that the new `datetime64` `dtype` will **not** at this date (2012/09) allow you to get properties like `days`.

Comment: Thanks. I do not understand your last paragraph though... are you saying if I instantiate the datetime object without any days then I can't get days back? Also I'm using datetime not datetime64, is there some advantage to datetime64?

Comment: @Dan `np.datetime64` is a new `dtype` in NumPy, optimized for NumPy. Your `MyArray[1]` has actually a `dtype=object`, *ie* it's a `ndarray` of objects, each object being a `datetime`. `object` dtype arrays are not as efficient as regular arrays...

Comment: are you saying that I should rather use numpy.datetime64 than datetime.datetime for this sort of application? Or are you saying that even though numpy.datetime64 is preferable, in this release it does not have the functionality to accomplish what I have described?

Comment: `np.datetime64` is still considered experimental at this date and I'm not sure whether it'll ever have the `.day`, `.hour`, ... properties